# how to change location on cordova with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keqm8.jpg)

```js
function loginState(){
      $.ajax({
          type : 'POST',
          url: "https://www.examplesite.com", 
          contentType : "application/json; charset-utf-8",
          data : JSON.stringify({
              action : 'appLoginState'
          }),
          success: function(result){
              if(result['state'] == false){
                  window.location.href = ("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
              }else if(result['state'] == true){
                  window.location = ('main.html');
              }
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error){
              alert(xhr.responseText);
          }
      }); 
  }
```

window.location.href = ("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); is not working.

Comment: what happens now when you use `window.location.href` ??

Comment: it runs once, i have a result but display is locked, anywhere cannot click because screen is constantly refreshed.

Comment: if(result['state'] == false){  
                    //window.location.href = "index.html"  
                }else if(result['state'] == true){  
                   //window.location.href = "main.html"  
                }

 app is run correctly when i make comment line